# Web server in wifi tethering

Tags: android, tethering

I want to develop an application which runs a Http server without any external modem i.e. both server and wifi tethering should be in same device.
Example lets say android devices A, B and C are there. Now device A will be tethering (wifi hotspot enabled) as well server has to run in it. So that device B and C can connect to it forming a client which can access the server. How do i do this. Pls help...

I tried using server ultimate app, but ended without success since it is working only when i'm connected with external wifi modem/mobile data.